# Recreating bursh on paper to stroke line in PS

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have the paper on which I have drawed little "sketch"[image]

And this "sketch" I need some how recreate, to look like it was done in photoshop with fill brush, and the edges remained rounded. For example
[image]

I tried more ways, how it can be do it, like selecting tool etc. but I did not succeed. Or exist any other program, who would be able to recreate it ?

Comment: It's quite unclear what is your problem. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Some how make from the first image, something like on second image.

Comment: very much related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85043/removing-background-and-cut-out-and-sharpen-handwritten-text