# How can I remove this message written by my deceased nephew so I can put his exact handwriting on tshirts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Chalkboard message]

How can I remove this message written by my deceased nephew so I can put his exact handwriting on tshirts?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried, or what has failed?

Comment: How experienced a user are you? Are you proficient with Photoshop? There may be some simple steps to get you partially there, however this is chalk on a "chalky" surface, it's going to take some advanced masking or adjusting. If you are truly interested in a quality image and don't have a lot of experience with Photoshop, it may be best to hire someone more adept with the tools. If quality is not so imperative that hiring a professional is an option... merely redraw things on a new layer by tracing the type using a brush. It may not be a photo of actual handwriting, but it can look identical.

Comment: Basic steps -- Invert then Levels or Curves adjustment.. then erase or mask away all the extra bits.

Comment: You might also try a few other questions here along these similar lines: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85043/removing-background-and-cut-out-and-sharpen-handwritten-text

Answer (score -1):

I made/started it for you.
[image]

I mostly used the 'blend if' options slider inside **layer styles** and a contrast adjustment. Here's the .psd and larger png, it should be a good starting point if you need to make edits.

[[PSD AND PNG LINK]](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/309c1ocgd9y8pv0/AAACDbWnBYKiTRDxz4wE552Qa?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: lol why would this get down voted?